# SQL Server and ADO.NET | Exception: "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

When trying to read the object coming back from SQL, I get this exception

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

C# code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PROC", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter ParamName1 = new SqlParameter("@Name1", "XYZ123");
    SqlParameter ParamName2 = new SqlParameter("@Name2", "1234");

    cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamName1);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamName2);

    con.Open();

    try
    {
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string result = rdr["Item"].ToString();
        }

        rdr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

SQL dynamic query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC]
    @Name1 VARCHAR(128),
    @Name2 VARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN                           
    --DECLARE @Name1 VARCHAR(128) = 'XYZ123',
    --        @Name2 VARCHAR(128) = '1234'
    --DECLARE @SelectFromTable VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SelectFromTable = 'SELECT [Item]
                            FROM [dbo].[' + @Name1 + ']
                            WHERE [ID] = ' + @Name2 + ' '

    EXEC (@SelectFromTable)
    --PRINT (@SelectFromTable)
END
```

**What I have tried**:

I have tested the dynamic SQL query in SQL Server by using the PRINT function to see that I'm getting the right data back from the executed statement, and indeed I am. I have looked over my C# code but cannot find the fault there.

**NOTE:** I am using `EXEC` instead of `sp_executesql` yeah, but I'd like to know why it isn't working with `EXEC`.

Comment: What is `rdr2`?  Is it different to `rdr`?

Comment: @Trevor Sorry, that should be rdr.

Comment: Shame, that would have perfectly explained the behaviour you were seeing :P

Comment: Could you try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` as the first statement of the stored procedure body, just after the first `BEGIN`?

Comment: @Trevor yeah lol, no good as well with the `SET NOCOUNT ON`

Comment: You need to wrap your table name in QUOTENAME to help mitgate sql injection. As posted, your code is wide open.

Comment: @SeanLange I know, but I want to see why as it stands, it is not working with exec.

Comment: As posted this won't even compile. And since you know you should be using sp_executesql trying to figure out why it isn't working with exec seems kind of pointless. Why bother fixing something you are going to change anyway?

Comment: @SeanLange it's a code snippet, it can't run because the complete code is impossible to post on Stack Overflow, and would take far too long to mock up. Even then, there seems to be a problem with the SqlDataReader since the query runs fine in SQL Server.

Comment: @AlexanderTolls can you try SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar,? Does that produce different results?

Comment: (cont) i.e. try  object res  =  cmd.ExecuteScalar(); If res == null, then it means there were zero rows in the result set. If res is DBNull.Value, it means there was a row, but the returned column was NULL (i..e Sql server NULL).

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic SQL looks like it could be wrong - try to replace:

`WHERE [ID] = ' + @Name2 + ' '`

with:

`WHERE [ID] = ''' + @Name2 + ''''`

Comment: This did not work, my dude, and I did try this before.

Comment: It was right also because it returned the right data.

Answer (score 0):

I would rework this to use sp_executesql. Something like this.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[PROC]
(
    @Name1 varchar(128), --for an object I would prefer to use sysname instead
    @Name2 varchar(128)
) AS
BEGIN                           
    DECLARE @SelectFromTable nvarchar(MAX)

    SET @SelectFromTable = N'SELECT Item
                            FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@Name1) + '
                            WHERE ID = @Name2'

    exec sp_executesql @SelectFromTable, N'@Name2 varchar(128)', @Name2 = @Name2
    --PRINT (@SelectFromTable)
END
```

Comment: With sp_executesql the same exception is thrown in Visual Studio. Thank you for providing an sp_executesql example, but the problem must be from the C# code, as both exec and sp_executesql run fine in SQL Sever.

Comment: It's happening exactly where the code snippet was posted, and was the result of setting up break points and debugging. This is why I posted the code snippet along with the SQL query.

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong with your dotnet code. It works perfectly. That is why the issue almost certainly must be in your sql.

Comment: @SeanLange I've done even more extensive tests since I posted the last comment and I can confirm that the SQL query is working exactly how it should. I have checked the SqlDataReader, and it returns exactly one field as it should, but with no value.

Comment: So you are saying it returns a single row and the value for the Item column is NULL? Even if that is the case your code should work. You would get an empty string.

Comment: @SeanLange It returns an object, since the field count is 1, but there is no data to read from it.